# Retrieve image names from sqlite

Tags: android

I have a database and I have two columns
Name of the first column: Img
Name of the second column: Name
I want to show them in Listview
There is no problem displaying names
But there is a problem with displaying pictures What is the solution?

ِAdbter Listview

```
public class adbter_listview extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    Activity activity;
    ArrayList<Integer> icons;
    ArrayList<String> name;

    public adbter_listview(Activity activity, ArrayList<Integer> icons, ArrayList<String> name) {
        super(activity, R.layout.custom_listview, name);
        this.activity = activity;
        this.icons = icons;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview, parent, false);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        iv.setImageResource(icons.get(position));
        tv.setText(name.get(position));
        return v;
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView con;
    ArrayList<String> icons_name = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> icons = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        con = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.con);


        db connect = new db(MainActivity.this);
        SQLiteDatabase read = connect.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor save = read.rawQuery("select image from game",null);
        save.moveToFirst();

        while(save.isAfterLast()==false)
        {
            icons_name.add(save.getString(0));
            icons.add(R.drawable.user);
            save.moveToNext();
        }


        adbter_listview adb = new adbter_listview(MainActivity.this,icons,name);
        con.setAdapter(adb);

    }

}
```

please help me

Comment: `But there is a problem with displaying pictures` which problem? What's wrong?

Comment: Your column names are Img and Name but you are selecting `image` ?? Also, you are adding drawable resource to your icon's arraylist not from your database

Answer (score 0):

Get int id of drawable using this line,

```
int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("nameOfDrawable", "drawable", this.getPackageName());
```

In your case

> nameOfDrawable = save.getString(0); I guess

then add into icons arrayList,

```
icons.add(drawableResourceId);
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: not work :( //////// while(save.isAfterLast()==false) { String nameOfDrawable = save.getString(0); int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("nameOfDrawable", "drawable", this.getPackageName()); icons_name.add(nameOfDrawable); icons.add(Integer.parseInt(save.getString(0))); save.moveToNext(); }

Comment: please you can help me :)

Comment: nameOfDrawable should not be string, put variable name there. 
write, drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(nameOfDrawable, "drawable", this.getPackageName());

Comment: Did you mean to put the database like this R.drawable.image ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
icons.add(R.drawable.user);
```

Use

```
icons.add(Integer.parseInt(save.getString(1)));
```

in adapter it should work only if the images are from drawables folder and use it like

```
R.drawable.icons.get(position)
```

But first remove the database call from the oncreate mainThread call to a different thread. Either create a new Thread or use asynctask or use loaders. Don't make a sqlitedatabase call in mainthread.

Comment: not work :( //////// while(save.isAfterLast()==false)
        {
            String  nameOfDrawable = save.getString(0);
            int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("nameOfDrawable", "drawable", this.getPackageName());
            icons_name.add(nameOfDrawable);
            icons.add(Integer.parseInt(save.getString(0)));
            save.moveToNext();
        }

Comment: please you can help me :)

Comment: is all the images in drawable folder only? Then why are you fetching it from the sqlite db? Is it for any project or you are learning?